# Use local assets in SonarQube 6.3.1 custom plugin's web page

Tags: plugins, sonarqube, html

I would like to insert some pictures in my custom web page for SonarQube 6.3.1. I tried to put it in resources/static like javascript files and call it with `<img src="image.png"></img>`but it doesn't work.

I do not really understand how SonarQube manage custom pages within the static folder. I followed the [official guide](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Extending+Web+Application) but I do not understand for example how to use external resources (images, html templates, etc.) in the js file of my page.

Thank you for your help,
Benoît

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found how to use my assets:

1. Put your assets in `src/main/ressources/static`, for example I added an image here `src/main/ressources/static/images/loading.gif`
2. Let myplugin my plugin's identifier
3. I am able to use my gif in `src/main/ressources/static/page.js` like this `<img src="../../static/myplugin/static/images/loader.gif"></img>`

Maybe it can help somebody...